# TCP Forceful routing through designated ethernet interface does not work in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, routing

I'd like to establish outgoing TCP path through any designated ethernet interface even if the designated ethernet interface is not configured as default gateway.

My device has two Ethernet Interface (eth0, eth1).

I'd like to establish TCP connection for eth0 (192.168.73.x) forcefully, even if default gateway is set to eth1 (192.168.83.1) instead of eth0 like below in routing table.

```
Destination     Gateway               Genmask             Flags   Metric   Ref    Use   Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.83.1          0.0.0.0             UG      0        0      0     eth1
192.168.73.0    0.0.0.0               255.255.255.0       U       0        0      0     eth0
192.168.83.0    0.0.0.0               255.255.255.0       U       0        0      0     eth1
```

To achieve this, I have created one socket and attached my source IP's address(=eth0) using bind api.

(I also tried using SO_BINDTODEVICE as well, but it didn't work)

And then I called connect api with destination IP's address  to connect to outside destination's public address

The code snippet is as below.

1>

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

2>

```
struct sockaddr_in  my_addr;

memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(0);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(myIP); // eth0's IP address (192.168.73.238)

bind(sock, (struct ::sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr) )
```

3>

```
struct sockaddr_in  dest_addr;
memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));

dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(destIp);        // Destination IP 
dest_addr.sin_port = htons(destinationPort);             // Destination Port

connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)(&dest_addr),sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

Error code returned by connect is "No route to host"

But this fails in my latest device with ubuntu linux 18.04 (kernel 4.15.18) whereas the same logic succeeds in my old device with old kernel version like 3.10 version.

Once I change default gateway from eth1 to eth0 and routing table becomes as below, then I can send outgoing packets via eth0.

```
Destination    Gateway         Genmask          Flags  Metric Ref    Use  Iface
0.0.0.0        192.168.83.1    0.0.0.0          UG     0      0      0    eth1
192.168.73.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0    U      0      0      0    eth0
192.168.83.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0    U      0      0      0    eth1
```

Actually I want to make it possible to establish outgoing path regardless of my default gateway configuration.

But it fails in latest ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15.18).

Is there any sysctl option I can try to make it work?

Or Is there anything I can try with kernel build option?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/where-can-i-ask-questions-for-networking you might have better luck on https://serverfault.com/ for network questions.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You'll have to define the routes/gateways needed for each desired destination depending on your topology; maybe your program has to run as root.

This is a routing quirk of the system, not of your programming. In every case of a packet ready to be sent, the system applies the network mask to the destination IP address to determine if that IP is located in a known network and then selects the output interface.

For example, if you send something to 192.168.73.25, applying the known masks 255.255.255.0 of your interfaces results in a network 192.168.73.0 (present in eth0), so it will be sent thru eth0 (as in your first configured routing table). If no interface has the desired destination network, then the packet is sent to the default gateway, which we already know is at 192.168.83.1, visible thru eth1.

All this is controllable using routing tables to alter the decision making of the system. So, if the destination is reachable thru eth0 you have to set up a new route indicating that. For example, if you want to send traffic to 192.168.12.35 and you know that this address is accesible from a router in the network connected to eth1, say, at the address 192.168.83.67, then you add a new route like this:

```
ip route add 192.168.12.65/32 via 192.168.83.67 dev eth1
```

Note that we cannot simply say "via eth1" because the destination IP is not in the 192.168.83.1-254 range of network addresses of eth1 (as indicated with the eth1 mask) and sending the packet thru that interface will not find automatically someone that knows where to resend it (and possible also don't know how to return an answer). Of course, to make the change permanent between reboots we have to configure the route in the netplan configuration.

If you have a topology with two ISPs (with one gateway to internet each), but only one is configured as the default gateway then you have to devise special routing tables that select the packet by destination IP or by port or by some other condition and send it thru the desired gateway. For this I recommend reading the [Linux Advanced Routing and Trafic Control HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/), or maybe implementing the [Net-ISP-Balance](http://lstein.github.io/Net-ISP-Balance/) script from Lincoln D. Stein that solves this kind of situations.

I apologize for the long text or assuming that you don't already know the routing mechanisms.

Note: Your program could change programmaticaly the routing tables if you know which routes you want, as the ip command do, but maybe it have to run with root privileges.

**EDIT:Reading about C routing programming, I found interesting code in [Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356), and in the [Oleg Kutkov Blog](https://olegkutkov.me/2019/08/29/modifying-linux-network-routes-using-netlink/).**

Comment: My program is running as a root. The curious thing is that same program runs perfect as I want in old linux kernel 3.10 version. but not in ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15.18). So I suspect some changes happened in Kernel side. Thanks~.

Comment: There is some routing notes in the [networking section](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.15#Networking-1) of the 4.15 [Release Notes](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions), and the [netlink man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) shows release related changes.